# Is it reasonable to generate mipmaps on the color attachment of my framebuffer in realtime?

Tags: opengl, graphics-programming

I'm looking into hdr tonemapping and so far all the equations I've found result in really, dulled results.

One i haven't tried uses an average luminance of the image. The pdf I've been reading suggests to generate mipmaps on my texture to get down to a single pixel that will then have average luminance.

However, in my tests this performs very slowly. I.e. I can't use it for realtime graphics.

Am I likely doing something wrong, or should I expect to be able to generate mipmaps for a framebuffer in realtime (I obviously need to generate them each frame).

If I shouldn't expect to be able to: Is there another method to glimpse average luminance of the image on screen?

Comment: Calculating mipmaps per-frame is fine, as long as you don't do it for several framebuffers/textures. I've actually seen (well-performing) AAA code that does exactly that for the average luminance. Perhaps the way you generate mipmaps is slow? what do you do?

Comment: I'm just using `glGenerateMipmaps`. I found that `glGenerateTextureMipMaps` crashes. I was only using it for a single texture (the color attachment of a framebuffer).